# How do I send a .json file as a HTTP POST using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest

I am new to most of these concepts, so I apologize if this question is trivial. I am trying to write a script that makes an HTTP POST request that sends a .json file containing an array of jsons. I am using an npm module found here: https://github.com/request/request
and a tutorial that walks you through using the module found here: 
http://samwize.com/2013/08/31/simple-http-get-slash-post-request-in-node-dot-js/

Here is the code I have so far:

```
//var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

  // Set the headers
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': "stuff",
    'x-authorization': "stuff"
  }

  // Configure the request
  var options = {
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/users/add',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      form: {
          'username': 'testuser42',
          'firstName': 'test',
          'lastName': 'user42',
          'password': 'testpassword'
      }
  }

  // Start the request
  request(options, function(error, response, body){
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body)
      }
  })
```

The data.json file I am trying to send to the local server will contain an array of jsons, formatted like so:

```
[
  {
    "username": "testuser1",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "user1",
    "password": "password1'
  },
  {
    "username": "testuser2",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "user2",
    "password": "password2'
  }
]
```

So I think I need to make separate POST requests for each array element, but it is not clear to me how to do this.

Comment: why do you think you need to do two separate requests?

Comment: I thought the body of my POST request could only contain one json object.

Comment: to answer your question, that entire data.json is a JSON file, therefore the entirety can be sent. the only thing you should ask yourself tis the potential size

Comment: The size of the array will be variable, it won't always contain just two objects.

Comment: check the boring answer i did,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is trivial example. The body needs to be a JSON type, doesnt matter the number of items, as long as the JSON is formatted properly your are good to go!

```
  const obj= {'msg': [
  {
    "username": "testuser1",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "user1",
    "password": "password1"
  },
  {
    "username": "testuser2",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "user2",
    "password": "password2"
  }
]};

request.post({
    url: 'your website.com',
    body: obj,
    json: true
  }, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

To include json file, just use require function like normal.

1: `const obj = require('./path_to/data.json');`

Comment: you can use promises here, instead of callbacks, just wanted to use the simplest example

Comment: another great alternative is Axios,

Comment: But in my case the 'obj' containing json items is in a separate, local file. So I guess what I'm asking is how to read that file into my script?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: alright if it helped, accept the answer for future OP. Your welcome

Comment: also you had single quotes somewhere in the json,